# What does "node size" refer to in the Random Forest?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, bagging

What is meant by node size in a Random Forest model? I understand what a decision node is, but not what is meant by node size.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A decision tree works by recursive partition of the training set. Every node $t$ of a decision tree is associated with a set of $n_t$ data points from the training set:

[image: n_t is the size of each node]

You might find the parameter `nodesize` in some random forests packages, e.g. [R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf): This is the **minimum node size**, in the example above the minimum node size is 10. The minimum node size is a single value: e.g. 10.

If splitting a node generates two nodes for which one is smaller than `nodesize` then the node is not split, and it becomes a leaf node.

It is actually a stopping criterion. This parameter implicitly sets the depth of your trees.

Setting this number to bigger values causes smaller trees to be grown (and thus take less time). Note that the default values are different for classification (default 1 in R) and regression (default 5 in R).

In other packages you directly find the parameter `depth`, e.g. [WEKA](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.html):

`-depth` from WEKA random forest package

The maximum depth of the trees, 0 for unlimited.
(default 0)

Comment: What are 'records'?  Do you mean data points?  Why is each node associated with a set of records?  I understand random forests quite well, but I do not know what the jargon means.

Comment: Yes, I meant data point. Usually you might refer to data points as records, instances, or examples.

Comment: So is there a rule of thumb minimum node size to avoid overfitting trees? I'd imagine it depends on the size of the training data so perhaps a certain proportion of the dataset size?

Comment: In random forests, trees are fully grown: node size is 1. Overfitting is avoided growing many trees. In decision tree it is more tricky. Trees are not fully grown and you have to perform pruning to avoid overfitting.

Comment: @Simone Thank you. What about the C5.0 model? Is it wise to always set the winnowing argument to TRUE?

Comment: It looks like winnowing is some sort of feature selection to simplify the tree and avoid overfitting. I guess pruning a single tree is always beneficial. Instead, winnowing can sometimes decrease the accuracy but it simplifies the tree.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what the function is of minimum node size? I'd frame it as a stopping criterion, for which a specific part of a tree is stopped growing when this number is reached.

Comment: @Archie the minimum node size is a single value: e.g. 10. If splitting a node generates two nodes for which one is smaller than `nodesize` then the node is not split, and it becomes a leaf node. It is actually a stopping criterion.

Comment: I understand. But maybe you could add this to the answer above? I find it not clear in its current state.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear if the nodesize is on the "in-bag" sampling or on the "out-of-bag" error.
If it is on the "out-of-bag" sampling, it is slightly more restrictive.